# PHP regex: How to remove ?file in url?

Tags: php, regex, replace

My url like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/movies/937-lan-kwai-fong-2?file=Rae-Ingram&q=
http://mywebsite.com/movies/937-big-daddy?file=something&q=
```

I want to get **"lan-kwai-fong-2"** and **"big-daddy"**, so I use this code but it doesn't work. Please help me fix it ! If you can shorten it, it is so great !

```
    $url= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
preg_replace('/\?file.*/','',$url);
preg_match('/[a-z][\w\-]+$/',$url,$matches);
$matches= str_replace("-"," ",$matches[0]);
```

Comment: Parse_url is the way to go http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Use the suggestion from the prev comment, and add to it a call to `parse_str` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php )

Comment: yes, what they said, and http_build_query if you need to reverse the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there are issue with your code which im going to go over because they are general things:

1. `preg_replace` does not work by reference so you are never actually modifying the url. You need to assign the result of the replace to a variable:

   ```
   // this would ovewrite the current value of url with the replaced value
   $url = preg_replace('/\?file.*/','',$url);
   ```
2. It is possible that `preg_match` will not find anything so you need to test the result

   ```
   // it should also be noted that sometimes you may need a more exact test here
   // because it can return false (if theres an error) or 0 (if there is no match) 
   if (preg_match('/[a-z][\w\-]+$/',$url,$matches)) {
     // do stuff
   }
   ```

Now with that out of the way you are making this more difficult than it needs to be. There are specific function for working with urls `parse_url` and `parse_str`.

You can use these to easily work with the information:

```
$urlInfo = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$movie = basename($urlInfo['path']); // yields 937-the-movie-title
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for perfect explanation !

Answer (score 0):

**Just replace**

```
preg_replace('/\?file.*/','',$url);
```

**with**

```
$url= preg_replace('/\?file.*/','',$url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex works, and parse_url is the right way to do it.  But for something quick and dirty I would usually use explode.  I think it's clearer.

```
@list($path, $query) = explode("?", $url, 2); // separate path from query
$match = array_pop(explode("/", $path));      // get last part of path
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
preg_match('/\/[^-]+-([^?]+)\?/', $url, $matches);
$str = isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : false;`
```

1. match last '/'
2. match anything besides '-' until '-'
3. capture anything besides '?' until (not including) '?'